# Insert label on chart area if there are no results

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm working with C# Windows Forms Charts, and I want to know if it is possible to show a big label saying "No Results" in Chart Area when there aren't any results in the chart.

Comment: For the ChartArea to show you still need to add one dummy point; make it Empty if you want.. Fedscribe how you add the points! DataBinding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would add a text annotation. You need to call it each time you add/remove/bind points.

```
void testEmpty(Chart chart)
{
    bool empty = true;
    foreach (var s in chart.Series)
    {
        if (s.Points.Any(x => !x.IsEmpty)) {empty = false; break; }
    }
    if (chart.Annotations.Contains(chart.Annotations["Empty"]))
        chart.Annotations.Remove(chart.Annotations["Empty"]);
    if (empty)
    {
        TextAnnotation ta = new TextAnnotation();
        ta.Name = "Empty";
        ta.X = 30;
        ta.Y = 45;
        ta.Text = "No Data!";
        ta.Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, 30f);
        chart.Annotations.Add(ta);
    }
}
```

You can play with the numbers; (50, 50 ) would place the top.left in the center of the chart (not chartarea)..

Note: For the `ChartArea` and its axes to show you still need to add one dummy point; make it `Empty` if you want..;

```
chart.Series.First().Points.Add(new DataPoint() { IsEmpty = true });
```

Comment: Note the small update to allow calling multiple times,,